# Как создать динамический массив объектов (конструктор обязателен)

Tags: c++, массивы, объекты, динамические-массивы, конструктор

Итак, допустим, у меня есть класс classarr, и у него нет конструктора по умолчанию.
В кач-ве параметра для конструктора передаётся строка.
У меня есть массив параметров для конструкторов будущих классов params, а так же кол-во элементов N.
Как можно создать динамический массив таких вот объектов?

---

Пробовал что-то типа `classar* qwerty = new classarr(params[0])[N];`,
хотел сначала просто сделать массив объектов, не важно, от какого параметра, а потом в цикле перезаписать, но вс ругается на такую запись, говорит, `не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "classarr" в "classarr *"`

---

Студент, 1 курс, можно что-нибудь относительно простенькое? :3

Comment: а почему бы не определить все нужные конструкторы?

Comment: Если N большое или не известно на этапе компиляции, то простенько этого не сделать. Надо будет делать по образцу ::std::vector

Comment: Ну, параметры заранее не известны, их количество тоже. Ладно, если не простенько, то хоть как-то )

Comment: @user7860670 Или взять сам `std::vector`.

Comment: Насчёт векторов, я попробовал, но там как-то мутно, ибо в цикле на три итерации, где я только пушил новые значения, у меня вызывались 6 раз деструкторы ).  
Лучшим решением пока остаётся добавление конструктора по умолчанию и сеттера

Comment: @sedo Вектор при изменении емкости будет пересоздавать свой динамический массив (чтобы изменить его размер), и для этого будет дерать конструкторы/деструкторы своих элементов. Это нормально. Если у вас класс от этого ломается, то [это плохой класс](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше все таки определить конструктор по умолчанию, инкапсулировать ваши данные и потом изменять их через специальные методы

```
class Something
{
private:
  const char* str;
public:
  Something() : str("") {}
  Something(const char* str) { this->str = str; }

  void set_str(const char* str) { this->str = str; }
  const char* get_str() const { return str; }
};
```

1. вариант без конструктора по умолчанию

   ```
    int main()
    {
      int N = 2;

      Something* arr = new Something[N]{ "a", "b" };

      delete[] arr;

      return 0;
    }
   ```
2. вариант c конструктором по умолчанию и использованием "сеттера"

   ```
    int main()
    {
      int N = 2;

      Something *arr = new Something[N];
      for (int i = 0;i < N;++i) {
        arr[i].set_str("a");
      }

      delete[] arr;

      return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите чего-то такого?

```
struct classarr
{
    classarr(const char * s):s(s){}

    const char * s;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    classarr* a = new classarr[3] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };

    cout << a[1].s;
}
```

Comment: Ну, по идее, да, но, наверное, либо в принципе не так делаю, либо проблемы с синтаксисом. Так как конструкторы разные и хранятся в массиве, мб это можно как-то сделать в цикле?

Comment: Добавьте конструктор по умолчанию (да хоть задавая значение параметра по умолчанию в имеющемся конструкторе) и функцию инициализации, которую потом вызовите в цикле.